# method adds to a list another method reads the list

Tags: c#, .net

How to make a method add to a List and another method reads the list to manipulate the data?

Idea is, Method-A gets the data and adds to List-A. Method-B reads the data after Method-A finishings looping through the list and does some work on the list.

Comment: Really not clear what you are trying to accomplish.  From what I can make of it it would seem that all you need to use are [the basic list methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6hkc2c4.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're doing multithreading, what you are probably looking for is a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd997371.aspx).
That makes it extremely easy to write threadsafe code for parallel processing work items.

If you are not multithreading, then you probably want a [`Queue<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977ey2c.aspx).

But your question doesn't really have enough detail to answer it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Just define the methods and pass in the `List`:

```
public void AppendData(List<SomeType> list) {
  // logic as per your requirements
}

public void ManipulateData(List<SomeType> list) {
  // logic as per your requirements
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a class that holds a private property that will be your list, and the two methods. The two methods will have access to the same list property without cluttering the rest of your app.